# función post no me toma la variable, solo un string directo

Tags: php, rest, guzzle

estoy asiendo 2 peticiones  una peticion rest con guzzle y una soap con curl, de la soap me regresa una url a la que le tiro la petición rest con guzzle

```
$responses = curl_exec($curl);
$client = new Client(['headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'] ]);
 $response = $client->post($responses,
    ['body' =>
        [
            'user' => 'xxxx',
            'pass' => 'xxxx'
        ]
    ]
);
```

si tiro asi la peticion me marca el siguiente error:

> GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 6: Could not
>   resolve host: %3Csoap:Envelope%20xmlns:soap=%22http in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/CurlFactory.php:126
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/CurlFactory.php(91):
>   GuzzleHttp\Ring\Client\CurlFactory::createErrorResponse(Array, Array,
>   Array) #1
>   /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/CurlHandler.php(96):

pero si la tiro así 
si me funciona 
con la url escrita directamente

```
$responses = curl_exec($curl);
$client = new Client(['headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'] ]);
 $response = $client->post('www.url.com/login',
    ['body' =>
        [
            'user' => 'xxxx',
            'pass' => 'xxxx'
        ]
    ]
);
```

alguien tiene alguna sugerencia

Comment: *pero si la tiro así*  ¿qué pasa si la tiras *así*? ...  No se entiende la pregunta. ¿Cuál es la petición soap, cuál es la petición guzzle?  ¿Cuál funciona, cuál no funciona? ¿Probaste a poner algo así: `$response = $client->post($curl,`  ? Aquí hay un error de sintaxis: `[''headers'`  hay una comilla simple de más.

Comment: Es que `curl_exec` no devuelve más que `TRUE` o `FALSE` ([ver Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-exec.php)), por tanto no puede funcionar. Al hacer esto: `$responses = curl_exec($curl);` la variable `$responses` será un booleno (resultante de la llamada a `curl_exec`) y por tanto aquí no estarías pasando una url válida, sino `TRUE` o `FALSE` según el caso: `$response = $client->post($responses,`  supongo que la URL se encuentra en la variable `$curl`, entonces, prueba a poner así, como ya te sugerí antes: **`$response = $client->post($curl,`**

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta es verdad que curl_exec($curl); me regresa un true o false pero si yo imprimo  $responses = curl_exec($curl);

      var_dump($responses);     me responde con la url string(253) "https://xxx.mx/xxx/rest" a esa url yo le concateno .'/login/signIn?=' para poder tirar la rest  imprimo de nuevo https://xxx.mx/xx/rest/login/signIn?=   y cuando la paso a guzzle para hacer la peticion en rest me tira error  a menos que esa url no este en variable si no en un string directo ' '

Comment: No entiendo. La URL con la que dices que funciona es esta: `www.url.com/login`, no tiene nada que ver con `xxx.mx/rest` ¿?

Comment: curl hace una petición soap  esta petición me regresa una url correspondiente a el dominio donde se encuentra este usuario... posteriormente  esta url la ocupo para logearme a este servidor   por eso necesito la respuesta de la petición curl

Comment: creo que curl no me esta regresado algo mas de lo que var_dum me dice si no que me regresa algo mas en xml pero no logro verlo  o como filtrarlo

Comment: listo <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:getWsdl xmlns:ns2="http://ws.login.xxx/"><return>https://xxx.mx/xxx/rest</return></ns2:geWsdResponse></soap:Body></soap>  la variable tenia un xml por debajo por eso no lo podía ver solo en código fuente

Comment: Ok, si lo hubieras puesto entre etiquetas `echo "<pre>";var_dump(.....); echo "</pre>";` quizá lo habrías visto. De hecho decía que había un `string(253) ` o sea 253 caracteres.

Comment: si gracias lo mire y medí cuenta lo pase por alto  es que jamas había consumido soap  pero era lógico que me regresara un xml gracias por el consejo, cambia tu comentario a respuesta para ponerlo como solucion